# Xcode - dyld: Symbol not found: __vtcOnSessionStart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've just recently started working with Xcode, trying to build iOS version of our Unity3D game that is already made for Android. The problem I'm having occurs when trying to start my app in Xcode simulator, tried to find my exact problem in here but nobody is mentioning "__vtcOnSessionStart". Full error message:

> dydl: Symbol not found: __vtcOnSessionStart
>
> Referenced
>   from:/Users/kostitch/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED13FE1B-5F33-4E82-8A68-66C59F043E0F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC7ED012-F851-4BF2-89DD-964C198C9300/basicbingotwo.app/basicbingotwo
>   Expected in: flat namespace

Comment: clean and try again. shift + cmd + K

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck, I've tried that couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I'm getting this in the iPhone Simulator when I try to call AddComponent on a script-created GameObject during another object's Awake() method. Removing this fixed the error.